# How to change the target directory of GCC compiler?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, directory, exe, target

It always puts the .exe file into the same directory as the source file. 

I'm not about to use any IDEs, just the command line tool.

Comment: Why don't you use `-o` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the -o flag.  You can give it a full path.

Comment: Everyone finds it for the first time sooner or later. It might as well be indexed by Google for everyone else. :)

Comment: I did. It's just that StackOverFlow makes you wait 11 minutes before you mark the right answer! xD